# Using laravel in domain.com/app folder

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, laravel-4

On a live server (not locally) I want to show my Laravel app like so:

`www.domain.com/app`, then it would show the site.

How can I do this?
Can .htaccess do this?

My .htaccess is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /dev
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Also have my routes as:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => 'domain.com/dev/'), function() {

Route::get('admin', 'AdminController@login');
Route::post('admin/postlogin', array('as' => 'admin.postlogin', 'uses' => 'AdminController@postlogin'));
Route::get('admin/dashboard', array('as' => 'admin.dashboard', 'uses' => 'AdminController@dashboard'));
Route::get('admin/dashboard', 'AdminController@dashboard')->before('auth');
Route::get('admin/logout', 'AdminController@logout');
Route::get('admin/pages','PagesController@index')->before('auth');
Route::get('admin/pages/create','PagesController@create')->before('auth');
 lots more routes but wont post them all.

 main one
  /*
 * Frontend
 */
Route::get('/{slug}', 'HomeController@showPage');
Route::get('/', function(){
    return Redirect::to('/home');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would actually create the folder on the server and upload all the files that are normally in the /public folder to this new /public/app folder.

Then edit the public/app/index.php to reflect this.

Change:

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

...

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/start.php';
```

To:

```
require __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/autoload.php';

...

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/start.php';
```

Hopefully then you shouldn't have to play around with your .htaccess or your routes file.

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar thing and this is what I used to it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app/$1 [L]
```